# Cannot get data from fetch javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I'm trying to generate token using fetch

```
fetch(baseUrl+`generate-token?exp=86400`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    )
.then((res) => res.json())
.then(({token})=>{


});
```

> My PHP code is this which generate token successfully :

```
public function generateToken()
   {
      $token = token();
      if($token){
         echo json_encode($token); exit;
      }
   }
```

but in `.then(({token})=>{` token variable it is still undefined.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: So what does `token()` return? Does the resulting JSON actually have a property `token`? If you remove the curly brackets from `({token})` and log it, what does it show then? (Structure wise, we don't need to see the actual token.)

Comment: what is the success response of this API endpoint  `baseUrl+`generate-token?exp=86400` can you update your question with the response?

Comment: Try without destructuring your code and see what is inside the json returned.

Comment: @DCodeMania response `"04AAAAAGNtAKMAEDE5MTN1NGNqMDNjdzNpOWQAcHpKHjSEqDt94Aw4Xd9mEqdr6XN"` is this when checked in Network tab response

Comment: @user3653474 Then don't destructure it. `({token})=>{}` means "take the property `token` from the incoming parameter and store it in the variable `token`". Your result doesn't have a property `token` (it isn't an object at all), so just use `token => {...}` and you should be golden.

Comment: @Ivar when i remove brackets then token variable is not undefined

Comment: @Ivar Thanks i will update it